# Solr DataImportHandler with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, solr

I'm having a problem getting Solr to talk to Microsoft SQL Server via the Microsoft JDBC Driver. I have the handler registered in solrconfig.xml:

```xml
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\Solr\conf\data-config.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

In data-config.xml I have a data source and a document defined:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" name="ds1"
    driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=myDB;responseBuffering=adaptive;"
    user="xxxx"
    password="xxxx"
    readOnly="true"
  />

  <document name="members">
    <entity name="member" datasource="ds1" pk="id"
      query = "select 
        MemberID as id,
        UserName as userName,
        FirstName as firstName,
        LastName as lastName,
        Birthday as birthday,
        PrimaryEmail as primaryEmail,
        PersonalStatement as personalStatement
        from member"
      transformer="DateFormatTransformer">
      <field column="Birthday" name="birthday" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    </entity>      
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

The columns are fairly irrelevant - I just wanted to start with a few items, including a date column. The Solr schema.xml has some fields defined:

```xml
<field name="id" type="tlong" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
<field name="userName" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="firstName" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="lastName" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="birthday" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="primaryEmail" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="personalStatement" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

When I attempt an import, the log shows an exception building the datasource:

> Jun 26, 2010 10:24:48 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter doFullImport
>   INFO: Starting Full Import
>   Jun 26, 2010 10:24:48 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
>   INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select params={clean=false&commit=true&command=full-import&qt=/dataimport} status=0 QTime=7 
>   Jun 26, 2010 10:24:48 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter readIndexerProperties
>   WARNING: Unable to read: dataimport.properties
>   Jun 26, 2010 10:24:48 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter doFullImport
>   SEVERE: Full Import failed
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: No dataSource :null available for entity :member Processing Document # 1
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.getDataSourceInstance(DataImporter.java:279)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.ContextImpl.getDataSource(ContextImpl.java:93)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.init(SqlEntityProcessor.java:52)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.init(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:71)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:319)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:242)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:180)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:331)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:389)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:370)
>   Jun 26, 2010 10:24:48 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
>   INFO: start rollback
>   Jun 26, 2010 10:24:48 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
>   INFO: end_rollback
>   Jun 26, 2010 10:24:54 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
>   INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select params={clean=false&commit=true&command=status&qt=/dataimport} status=0 QTime=0

I've read the FAQ and documentation, looked at as many sources as I can find, and I just can't get past this error. What am I doing wrong? The error "Unable to read: dataimport.properties" appears to be shown any time there is any issue with the configuration. I can't find my mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the datasource is not recognized in the entity declaration because the proper attribute to use is `dataSource`, not `datasource`